# PHPUnit - Zend framework 3 - testing stubs that redirect

Tags: php, automated-tests, zend-framework3, phpunit

I am trying to write phpunit test cases that can check functionalities of my website like Register and Login.

I am struggling to write these phpunit test cases from past few days. The code is already written and i am suppose to write the phpunit test cases for them. To do this i have implemented the code as given below

```
$this->getRequest()
    ->setMethod('POST')
    ->setPost(new Parameters($_POST));
    $this->dispatch('/default/register');
    $this->assertModuleName('default');

    //assertActionName
    $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
    $this->assertControllerName(MyDefaultController::class);
    $this->assertControllerClass('MyDefaultController');
    $this->assertActionName('register');
    $this->assertMatchedRouteName('register')
```

I am finding difference in the behaviour of code on browser (where it runs just fine) and the phpunit case. In case of phpunit, i get the response 303 and the registration does not happen. When i checked further in the code, i found that Zend framework uses $prg method to do internal redirects. So i am getting response in my phpunit case just after the first redirect. And so the status code = 303 but the registration does not happen.

On the other hand browser handles this properly and follows the redirect and registration works just fine.

How can i achieve the same result for functionalities that redirect url internally like Register/Login in case of phpunit?

Comment: Why are you asserting for 200 OK and not for the 303 REDIRECT? (The redirect also happens within your browser, it's just that the browser follows the redirect.) Did you read: https://docs.zendframework.com/zend-test/assertions/#redirect-assertions ?

Comment: @k0pernikus my idea of writing the phpunit test case is to ensure that registration works fine. So even if i assert on 303, the registration still did not happen from the php unit test case at that point in time. So the question is how do i follow the urls in my phpunit test case, the way browser does?